# Custom serving static content with CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am trying to figure out how to customize static content serving with cherrypy.

The objective is to serve files when the path starts with /pub as per normal, but when the path starts with anything else I want to add a custom function that first checks access.

The documentation give me enough. Here is what I have so far...

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file
class Root(object):
    # Somehow turn this into a handler for all files
    def page(self):
        if authorized(): # Check whether authenticated user may access the requested path
            file_location = .... # Work out file location from request
            print("Serving file from %s" % file_location)
            return serve_file(file_location)
        else:
            return "Not Authorized"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve_conf = {'/': {'tools.gzip.on': True},
                  '/pub': {
                        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                        'tools.staticdir.dir': "/data/public",
                        'tools.staticdir.debug': True,
                        'log.screen': True
                        },
                  '/secure': { "PROBABLY CONFIGURE THE HANDLER HERE" }
                  }
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), config=serve_conf)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have more or less worked it out by painful trial and error.  This is my first "Tool"

```python
from os.path import basename

import cherrypy
import os

from cherrypy import Tool
from validator.util import validate_bearer_header

# Returns the "signing secret" file from the handler application
def get_signing_secret(*args):
    signing_secret = cherrypy.request.app.cdn_signing_secret
    return signing_secret

# A tool that can be used to "protect" resources that requires authentication
def protect(*args):
    subject_resource = basename(cherrypy.request.path_info)
    supplied_auth = cherrypy.request.headers.get("Authorization", None)
    if not supplied_auth:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError("401 Not Authenticated")
    token_test_result = validate_bearer_header(supplied_auth, get_signing_secret())
    if not token_test_result:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError("401 Not Authenticated")
    if not token_test_result.get("sub") == subject_resource:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError("403 Unauthorized")


class Root(object):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            with open(cherrypy.config["cdn_signingkey.filename"], 'r') as secretfile:
                self.cdn_signing_secret = secretfile.read().replace('\n', '')
            print("CDN signing secret obtained")
        except:
            print("ERROR reading CDN signing secret file")
            raise
        cherrypy.tools.protect = Tool('before_handler', protect)

    # TODO Add exposed handlers to allow automated master/slave CDN file replication


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cdn_server.conf')
    cherrypy.config.update(conf_file)
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), config=conf_file)
```

The entries in my config file that pertains to the app is:

```python
[/]
tools.gzip.on = True

[/pub]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "/data/cdn/public"
tools.staticdir.debug = True
log.screen = True

[/secure]:
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "/data/cdn/secure"
tools.staticdir.debug = True
log.screen = True
tools.protect.on = True
```

I would prefer to define get_signing_secret as a member of the app class and then access `self.cdn_signing_secret` instead of the method above, but I can't figure out how to handle "self" passed to a Tool.

Comment: Please look at the [example of an auth tool](https://github.com/GDG-Ukraine/gdg.org.ua/blob/master/src/GDGUkraine/lib/tools/authorize.py), it uses class `cherrypy.Tool` and [is being registered via simple assignment](https://github.com/GDG-Ukraine/gdg.org.ua/blob/master/src/GDGUkraine/lib/tools/__init__.py#L7). I hope this will help you to wrap your code into a class.